# Using sum function inside reduce

Tags: python, python-3.x, functools

I was trying to use the built-in function "sum" inside the reduce function from the functools modules, but I got an error, would you please help on this?

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
from functools import reduce
reduce (sum,l)
```

---

the error that I got is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-19-6309b57d2b6d> in <module>
----> 1 reduce (sum, l,0)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve: what effect are you trying to achieve? This isn't the right way to use `reduce`, but we could help better if you tell us what output you're looking for. If you just want the sum of `l`, use `sum(l)`; no need for `reduce`.

Comment: `sum` is a special case of `reduce`: `reduce(operator.add, l)`.

Comment: ``reduce`` needs a function of the signature ``(T, T) -> T`` – e.g. ``operator.add`` which takes two ``int`` and provides one ``int``. ``sum`` is of the form ``(Iterable[T], T) -> T``, i.e. not adequate for ``reduce``. What result do you expect from making this call?